# Replace Vector by Arraylist (insertElementAt problem)

Tags: java, list, arraylist, vector

I have to replace the given code using Vector like:

```
Vector<String> myList = new Vector<>();
myList.add(...);
myList.add(...);
myList.add(...);
myList.insertElementAt(something, 0);
```

My approach was using something like this:

```
List<String> myList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
myList.add(...);
myList.add(...);
myList.add(...);
```

But how to replace `insertElementAt` easily?

Comment: How about `myList.add(0, something);`?

Comment: perfect, that helped a lot. so easy sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `set()` function to insert an element at a specific index.

```
myList.set(index,element)
```

As ArrayList stores element in continuous order, there will be a shuffling of elements after that element. Read more about `List` functions from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: ok then if you want to add an element to an index then use 'myList.add(index, element);' function

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to SynchronizedList, and use.

Like:

```
((SynchronizedList)myList).set(index, element)
```